# project file line suppression state error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException while building wowonder app

Tags: c#, xamarin

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Noitvonne\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\codecanyon-AomdQBjJ-mobile-native-timeline-applications-for-wowonder-social-php-script\Timeline_V3.7\WoWonder\obj\Debug\110\lp\139\jl\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png'.
at System.IO.`enter code here`__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination)
at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.ExtractAll(ZipArchive zip, String destination, Action`2 progressCallback, Func`2 modifyCallback, Func`2 deleteCallback, Func`2 skipCallback)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(IDictionary`2 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.RunTask()
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   WoWonder

Answer (score 0):

for this error the problem is may be while unzipping the downloaded file you might face problem of unzipping and the folder name that you have assigned to your project is way too long ...
while unzipping , just make sure you are entering/ modifying file path or file name way shorter ... about 20-25 letters.
And now open project in visual studio ...
Double click on solution of project and then build solution.
Your app will run without any issues.